# does DNS speed differs by type of domain? .com / .nu / .io

Tags: dns

If I register same domain name:

- www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.io
- www.mysite.nu

and point all to same DNS servers, is that possible to one response faster than other?

I'm asking because my NU domain seems to be slow and I'm using this tool to check speed: https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsHostingSpeedResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each top-level domain has their own set of nameservers and they can certainly vary in number, location and performance.

E.g. when resolving `mysite.nu`, the DNS resolver must first ask one of the well-known root nameservers for the authoritative nameservers for the `.nu` top-level domain (turns out there are only three), pick one at random (e.g. `b.nic.nu`) and ask that nameserver for the location of nameservers for `mysite.nu`.

The country code (two character) top-level domains tend to concentrate their nameservers in a particular geographical region, and might therefore work faster for clients in the same region.

Comment: is this the reason why facebook uses akamaid.NET domain for static content? can .NET generic-top-domain be faster than other country-top-level domains?

Comment: I don't think DNS is of any concern (any DNS latency only costs on the first access, after that it is cached in your own computer for any further requests typically for a day or so). Akamai consists of a wast network of content servers that are capable of serving static content efficiently without loading any of facebook's own servers.